# When I pull json data I want the text to show up on same row as the image with a little spacing in between. How do i accomplish this?

Tags: html, css

```js
var twitchArr = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];

var dataArray;
twitchArr.forEach(function(twitch) {
  $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + twitch + '?client_id=lgiuraoc2wbg635m7ewteblxg38n4b', function(data) {
    console.log(data.stream); /*just for checking*/
    if (data.stream !== null) {
      forOnline(data.stream.channel.logo, data.stream.channel.game, data.stream.channel.status);

      function forOnline(img, gameName, description) {
        var para = '<img id="mainImg" src=' + img + '>' + '<p id="textovo">' + gameName + ": " + description + '</p>';


        $("#onlineImage").append(para);

      }
    } else {
      console.log(data._links.channel);
      let toHitUrl = data._links.channel;
      toHitUrl += '?client_id=lgiuraoc2wbg635m7ewteblxg38n4b';
      console.log(toHitUrl);
      $.getJSON(toHitUrl, function(imglogo) {
        forOffline(imglogo.logo, 'offline');

        function forOffline(img, description) {
          var para = '<div class="off2">' +
            '<img id="mainImg" src=' + img + '>' + '</div>';
          var para1 = '<div class="off3">' + '<p id="textovo">' + description + '</p>' + '</>';
          $('#offlineImage').append(para);
          //$('#textSecond1').append(para1);
        } //for when offline use this

      });
    } //end of getJson
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 1em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}


/* apply a natural box layout model to all elements, but allowing components to change*/


/*html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}*/

.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 3px solid yellowgreen;
  height: 50em;
  width: 50em;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.mainCont {
  background-color: rgb(177, 175, 175);
  width: 30em;
  height: 5em;
}

.onlineContainer {
  width: 40em;
  height: 5em;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

#onlineImage {
  height: 5em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Twitch Tv Project</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="twitchcss.css">

  <!--jquery link-->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" />


  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <!--main container-->
      <div class='mainCont'>
        <!--heading container-->
        <h3 id="twitchHead">TWITCH STREAMERS</h3>
      </div>
      <!--end of heading container-->

      <div class='onlineContainer'>
        <div id="onlineImage"></div>
      </div>
      <!--end of online container-->

      <div class='offlineContainer'>
        <div id="offlineImage"></div>
      </div>
      <!--end of offline container-->
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="twitchjs.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

I am pulling json data and i want to append image and text side by side with little spacing in between. However I keep getting the text below the image. How do i get the text that the data is pulling to show side by side of the image instead of wrapping over to next line? flex-wrap doesnt seem to work.

```js
function forOnline(img, gameName, description) {
  var para = '<img id="mainImg" src=' + img + '>' + '<p id="textovo">' + gameName + ": " + description + '</p>';


  $("#onlineImage").append(para);
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 3px solid yellowgreen;
  height: 50em;
  width: 50em;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.mainCont {
  background-color: rgb(177, 175, 175);
  width: 30em;
  height: 5em;
}

.onlineContainer {
  width: 40em;
  height: 5em;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <!--main container-->
    <div class='mainCont'>
      <!--heading container-->
      <h3 id="twitchHead">TWITCH STREAMERS</h3>
    </div>
    <!--end of heading container-->

    <div class='onlineContainer'>
      <div id="onlineImage"></div>
    </div>
    <!--end of online container-->

    <div class='offlineContainer'>
      <div id="offlineImage"></div>
    </div>
    <!--end of offline container-->
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="twitchjs.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: There is an error in your code snippet so it's unfortunately unhelpful.

Comment: fixed now, added full working code

Answer (score 0):

I would call the flex css on either #onlineImage or .onlineContainer. I would also try using justify content to center the items on the same line, so something like this perhaps. Let me know if this works for you

```
.onlineContainer{  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: i put this on #onlineImage and it puts the text beside the image, but because its pulling two sets of these, both are on the same line. Also why is it that I have to put display flex again even though i did it for the main container? is it because this is a separate container?

Comment: ah, didnt see your full code at the top of the page, based on what i can see your main problem is the set heights of 5em for #onlineImage and .onlineContainer.  delete those and call display:flex on onlineImage

Comment: this does the job of putting the text next to image, but now a set is side by side, instead of one below the other